# How to install Linux from a UEFI bootable, overwriting an existing Windows installation

Tags: linux, partition, uefi, bios, bootable

I am on an older netbook that cannot handle Windows 10 (nor Windows 11) anymore since the 64 GB fixed flash memory cannot handle the data.
It is a Medion Akoya netbook, model number: MD 61900, model: E2228T. Obviously, this question is not bound to just this special choice of hardware.

There are [50 similar questions on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=install+Linux+UEFI+BIOS+from+usb+overwrite+windows), but just because of that, I could not find a clear help of how to over-install Linux on a Windows installation using UEFI and a Linux bootable.

Thus: how to *really* just do it?

Comment: It varies somewhat by brand/model system as some need different settings or procedures. And it will depend on video card/chip, nvidia really needs proprietary driver to work well. Age or spec of system makes a difference. Old systems will work better with a Lightweight distribution. Very new hardware needs newest kernel & drivers or latest distribution and then maybe newer kernel. You did not give any info on what hardware nor which distribution, so difficult to be specific. Otherwise all 50 other questions are probably good.

Comment: @oldfred I added something more about the hardware.

Comment: The more mainstream the system is, the better it is supported. Yours does look like it has Intel CPU, but ease of install my depend on other support chips. Since limited system, you want a lightweight install. I use Kubuntu which is a midweight system. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie There are many other distributions that are lightweight. It may just depend on what drivers are supported whether it works well on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. Save any data that might be on the existing devices of the hard drive. If you want, save the license code of the installed Windows and other software, there are tools that can read it out.
1. Restart and press `F2` at startup. Switch `Secure Boot` of the `Security` tab to `Disabled`:

[image]

2. Connect with a Linux bootable for GPT. I used the Linux Mint 20.2 image (which is just one out of a wide range of distributions, choose yourself) and put it on a micro SD card using the free software "rufus", a small executable, no need to install it. In some cases, it might be needed to use USB instead of a flash card. At least in my case, the card slot was somehow not active, but the same card could be used as a bootable using a USB adapter.
3. Save and restart

[image]

and press `F9` at startup (or start with the NOVO button if you have it, it is a small button usually next to the power button) to enter the UEFI menu where you choose the Linux bootable.

In my case, it opened the Linux menu directly without the mentioned UEFI menu in between:

[image]

4. Start "Install Linux Mint".

[image]

5. When asked, choose to unmount the partitions in use (if you want to overwrite Windows).
6. When asked, click in the middle of the three checkboxes to clean the disk and install Linux. You may also choose "Advanced features" and encrypt your whole disk with LVM. The disk will then need to be unencrypted by a password at every startup. I recommend this for a laptop which can always get stolen or lost.
7. When asked, choose `Continue` to *really format all of the listed devices* - since you want to clean the disk from the existing Windows installation.